# R: different functions report different sizes for the same dataframe

Tags: r, na

I have a dataframe that I created from reading a csv file with the following properties:

```
'data.frame':   1290 obs. of  9 variables:
 $ Date            : Factor w/ 1290 levels "1/3/2020 00:00",..: 97 98 99 100 101 102 103 104 105 106 ...
 $ Moisture.20.0   : num  39.8 40 40.1 40.1 40.2 ...
 $ Moisture.46.0   : num  40.9 40.9 40.9 40.9 40.9 ...
 $ Temperature.20.0: num  32.6 32.7 33 33.4 33.7 ...
 $ Temperature.46.0: num  32.3 31.9 31.9 31.8 31.8 ...
 $ EC.20.0         : num  0.302 0.303 0.305 0.309 0.313 ...
 $ EC.46.0         : num  0.511 0.507 0.507 0.507 0.507 ...
 $ Field.ID        : int  6466 6466 6466 6466 6466 6466 6466 6466 6466 6466 ...
 $ Sensor.loc      : Factor w/ 1 level "-00.0000000 00.0000000": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

You can see it has 1290 rows for 9 variables.

However, when I proceed to determine if there are any NA values inside my dataset I get `TRUE`.

```
any(is.na(df))

[1] TRUE
```

I know for a fact that this particular csv does not have NAs. Furthermore, I use the `which()` function to determine where in my dataframe I can find the NAs but get weird results:

```
which(is.na(df))

[1] 1799 6959
```

If I understand correctly, the call is returning two index values where I will find NAs: [1799, ] and [6959, ].

What I do not understand is why I'm given these values if my original dataset only has 1290 as per the `str()` function call.

Does the `which()` function recognize different dimensions than `str()`? How can I trust `which(is.na(df))` to provide me the correct indices for me to check-on and deal with NAs?

Comment: Hi Sergio, could you maybe share the whole CSV, for example by putting it on Github so we can access it by URL? Thanks.

Comment: It might help to do `which(is.na(df), arr.ind = TRUE)` so you can better see which elements are `NA`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that 1799 is not the 1799th *row*, it's the 1799th *element*, column-wise.

```r
dat <- mtcars[1:4,]
dat[3,3] <- NA
dat
#                 mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
# Mazda RX4      21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
# Mazda RX4 Wag  21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
# Datsun 710     22.8   4   NA  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
# Hornet 4 Drive 21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
which(is.na(dat))
# [1] 11
```

That 11 includes: 4 from column 1, 4 from column 2, and the 3rd element in column 3. If you wanted to do the math, then

```r
isna <- which(is.na(dat))
(isna - 1) %% nrow(dat) + 1
# [1] 3               # row of the NA
(isna - 1) %/% nrow(dat) + 1
# [1] 3               # column of the NA

ind2arr <- function(ind, nr) cbind((ind-1) %% nr + 1, (ind-1) %/% nr + 1)
ind2arr(which(is.na(dat)), nrow(dat))
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    3    3

### demo
ind <- seq_len(prod(dim(dat)))
cbind(ind, ind2arr(ind, nrow(dat)))
#       ind     
#  [1,]   1 1  1
#  [2,]   2 2  1
#  [3,]   3 3  1
#  [4,]   4 4  1
#  [5,]   5 1  2
#  [6,]   6 2  2
#  [7,]   7 3  2
#  [8,]   8 4  2
# ...truncated...
# [41,]  41 1 11
# [42,]  42 2 11
# [43,]  43 3 11
# [44,]  44 4 11
```

Or better, add `arr.ind=TRUE` to get better perspective.

```r
which(is.na(dat), arr.ind = TRUE)
#            row col
# Datsun 710   3   3
```

Answer (score 1):

It's easy to test what' going on with a simple mock-up

```r
df <- data.frame(a = 1:3, b = c(1:2, NA))

is.na(df)
         a     b
[1,] FALSE FALSE
[2,] FALSE FALSE
[3,] FALSE  TRUE

which(is.na(df))
[1] 6
```

So, even though I have 3 rows, it is the 6th element of `df` that is `NA`

As @r2evans points out, you can find your culprits with;

```
which(is.na(df), arr.ind = TRUE)
     row col
[1,]   3   2
```